# L'origine du c cédille

Tags: orthographe, histoire, diacritiques, alphabet

Le c cédille, lorsqu'introduit en français, était une lettre du [castillan](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%87) aujourd'hui disparue de l'espagnol.

- Quelles sont les circonstances de cet emprunt ? À quand remonte-t-il ?

Comment: @jlliagre « Dans le français » se dit aussi, bien que ce n'est jamais pour dire « en termes de langue française »; pourquoi ne pas coder ici clairement qu'il s'agit d'un apport au langage, c'est à dire dans le langage, puisque « dans le français » est correct? Il existe donc un usage  figé d'après vous?

Comment: Je ne peux m'empêcher de mentionner la réponse humoristique du *chat* de Philippe Geluck: la cédille a été inventée par un certain Monsieur Duçon..

Comment: Libre à toi de remettre cette forme pour le moins maladroite. Je n'y aurais pas touché s'il n'y avait eu ce *lorsque introduit*...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je suis loin d'être spécialiste, mais je pense que les liens ci-dessous (questions sur FSE) peuvent donner des indications et constituent un bon point de départ (voir aussi les références mentionnées dans les réponses) :

[Regarding usage and history of special character/symbols/diacritics in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18721/regarding-usage-and-history-of-special-character-symbols-diacritics-in-french)

[What exactly do the French diacritics denote? And can they be implied/expelled?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25121/what-exactly-do-the-french-diacritics-denote-and-can-they-be-implied-expelled)

Mon Littré indique :

> Espagn. cedilla ; ital. zediglia ; diminutif de zêta, nom du z en grec
>   ; la cédille a été ainsi nommée, parce que, d'ordinaire, pour donner
>   au c le son de l's, on écrivait cz : leczon pour leçon.

La [Grammaire méthodique du français](https://www.amazon.fr/Grammaire-m%C3%A9thodique-fran%C3%A7ais-Martin-Riegel/dp/2130732852/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1542978648&sr=8-2&keywords=grammaire%20methodique%20du%20francais) en parle aussi :

[image]

Another source I found [A Reference Grammar of French](https://books.google.fr/books?id=r8L3CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT108&lpg=PT108&dq=cedilla%20french%20reference%20grammar&source=bl&ots=pFuzOxrKai&sig=IOQiCRDYJvNdBRLmXMikVJglcog&hl=el&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia4ur0u_DeAhUugM4BHUb3CJYQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=cedilla%20french%20reference%20grammar&f=false)

> The term “cedilla” comes from the diminutive of the Spanish zeta/zeda
>   (z), which disappeared from use in the eighteenth century. The cedilla
>   appears like an upside-down c, and is placed beneath the consonant c
>   when it is followed by an a, o or u. This indicates that the c is to
>   be pronounced as an ss, and not like a k: le franc¸ais, nous
>   commençons, j’ai rec¸u. The cedilla is also used with capitals.

Of course [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedilla) offers a plethora of information. Here is the [French page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9dille). Here is an interesting [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ACedilla#Does_anybody_know_the_origin_of_cedilla?).
Another link that discuss cedilla in general.

http://diacritics.typo.cz/index.php?id=8

> The shape of the cedilla origins in the lower part of cursive
>   lowercase z, and its name comes from old Spanish name of the
>   character. In Spanish, it is not used since the reform of orthography
>   in the 18th century, when it was replaced by the letter z. Most
>   commonly, cedilla appears below the letter c (ç) in Western Roman
>   languages where it represents the “s” sound where the “c” would
>   represent the “k” sound. In Turkish, it is also used with s (ş).
>
> In Cameroon, languages using the General Alphabet for Cameroon
>   Languages (GACL) have the cedilla under vowels to indicate
>   nasalization, like the ogonek is used in some European or American
>   languages. GACL uses a wide range of letters for vowels : basic Latin
>   vowels (a̧ ȩ i̧ o̧ u̧), schwa (ə̧), Latin epsilon or open E (ɛ̧), open
>   O (ɔ̧) and I with stroke (ɨ̧).

---

NB (citant @Eau qui dort)

la raison pour laquelle l'espagnol utilisait un z (et pas un s) pour marquer le son /s/ est que cette langue faisait à l'époque une distinction entre un /s/ avancé touchant presque les dents (comme /s/ en français moderne) épelé c, z ou ç, et un /s/ rétracté prononcé près des alvéoles (le /s/ de l'espagnol moderne) épelé /s/ ou /ss/. Le français ayant déjà fusionné les deux phonèmes, il a emprunté la cédille pour représenter son /s/ avancé.

Comment: Note: la raison pour laquelle l'espagnol utilisait un z (et pas un s) pour marquer le son /s/ est que cette langue faisait à l'époque une distinction entre un /s/ avancé touchant presque les dents (comme /s/ en français moderne) épelé c, z ou ç, et un /s/ rétracté prononcé près des alvéoles (le /s/ de l'espagnol moderne) épelé /s/ ou /ss/. Le français ayant déjà fusionné les deux phonèmes, il a emprunté la cédille pour représenter son /s/ avancé.